# Problems with repeatedly calling a member function in which vector summation is implemented

Tags: c++

We have a large loop that need to call this member function repeatedly. It's expected that in each iteration of the loop, the calculation time should be similar. But in our calculation, it becomes much slower gradually when the number of iteration increases. We have found that this is induced by this member function. I don't quite understand why it happens. Can anyone explain it for me? or any suggestions for this kind of summation calculation for vectors?

Basic implementation of this part of code:

Dataunit is a class defining the data structure in which several vectors are declared and defined in its member functions.

predict is an object pointer defined in the class Residue which is assigned a value beforing using here. Basically, before calling respdef() function, The data that Y points to are calculated and its pointer can be accessed by calling dataOutput() . Also numExp and numResp are member variables of Residue which are valued in constructor at definition.

In each step, this function will be called to form Yt according to the values of Y. For example, if the loop is 10000 steps, this function would be called 10000 times. It's expected that the size of Yt are changed slightly which is based on the caculation of the data set Y points to. But this size wouldn't change much.

```
int Residue::respdef()
{
  int m,i;
  Dataunit tem; //defining a objective of class Dataunit
  const Dataunit* Y=predict->dataOutput(); //dataOutput () returns a pointer 
  //Size of Yt is set to zero and redefined using push_back and initialization
  Yt.clear(); 
  for(m=0;m!=numExp;m++)
  {
      Yt.push_back(tem);
      //initialization is a function  to define and initialize Yt.
      Yt[m].initialization(Y[m].tvector.size(),numResp);    
      for (i=0;i!=Y[m].tvector.size();i++)
      {
      Yt[m].tvector[i]=Y[m].tvector[i]; //Copying Y[m].tvector to Yt[m].tvector
      Yt[m].Tvector[i]=Y[m].tvector[i];//Copying Y[m].Tvector to Yt[m].Tvector
      Yt[m].resp[0][i]=Y[m].resp[0][i];
      Yt[m].resp[1][i]=Y[m].resp[0][i]+Y[m].resp[1][i];
      Yt[m].resp[2][i]=Y[m].resp[0][i]+Y[m].resp[1][i]+Y[m].resp[2][i];
      Yt[m].resp[3][i]=2*Y[m].resp[4][i];
      }
  }
  return 1;  
}
```

Thanks guy for helping me here. The problem is not in this part of code. I just realize that I changed the function for calculating the data Y points to by adding a push_back in order to prevent data incomplete. So the size of Y increase in every loop which induce the size increase of Yt here.  I need to resize Y in every step. Thank you

Comment: Just remove all the code except the `return 1;`, because that is always the result? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by calling `push_back` on an unreserved `vector`. `std::vector` stores all its objects in contiguous memory on the heap. It starts off reserving memory(usually in powers of 2) based on the initial need and keep reallocating more when needed. However, there is no way of asking the heap to move the squatters sitting right where your `vector`s current memory allocation ends and allocate it to you instead. Instead, the `vector` asks the heap for an amount of more equal to the new size it wants and moves(if possible, copies otherwise) all its underlying objects from the old location to the new one. Thus, starting from an empty vector, time taken to populate it with `n` objects isn't linear in `n`. If you have an idea of how big your vector is going to be, you can help the compiler out and call `std::vector::reserve`. This will help minimize the number of reallocations and reduce the associated overhead.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. What you said is right and I am aware of this. Here Yt is initially defined and initialized in the constructor. Besides, the size of Yt is redefined with clear() so that the size of Yt won't gradually increase by using push_back. This leads me to double that the situation you said won't happen here. But I think using reserve is a good idea to prevent from reallocating or moving the vector in some other cases.

Comment: There's a difference between size and capacity of the vector. While implementation dependent, capacity usually doesn't decrease. So, calling `clear()` resets the size, but doesn't free the memory. This isn't necessarily a bad thing. For one, it ensures that the next time to start pushing elements to this vector, you have no reallocations until the previous capacity was exceeded. That said, as a thumb rule, always use `reserve`.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with u on using reserve in the code when vector size changes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it could be a lot of things.   This is really lousy code that needs a lot of clean up.   Where did "predict" and Yt come from?   Are they member variables, or globals?   What about numExp and numResp?  Are they constants, member variables or globals?   Since the code is pretty poorly written and not very descriptive, it is hard to make much sense of it from a small snippet.   There could be all kinds of crazy operator overloading going on that causes the vectors to grow, etc.   It is also not clear what other outside factors may be involved.

The best option would be use a profiler to start with.   If you don't have that, you might set some breakpoints with hit counts and look at the vectors and see if they are growing over subsequent calls.   Finally, you could add some counting of loops and log that at the end to see if the number of loops is dramatically increasing over time.   If both numExp and Y[m].tvector.size() continue increase, then time spent in this method will quickly worsen.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm in a hurry for posting this so I didn't make it very clear earlier. I add some illustration this time. Hope someone can give me some thoughts on this. The other parts of the code can be run smoothly, which we have tested in other cases. But adding this function, the calculation becomes slower and slower when the number of iteration increases. We didn't change the other code, so I guess it's this part that causes the problem. Before posting this, I also use valgrind to detect if there is memory leak, but we didn't find any.